# MAGMI can't update magento product images

Tags: magento, magmi

I'm using magmi to create and update products and their images. The problem is that MAGMI does not update the images if the image already exists. It works to create new images but not to update existing ones.

At Image attributes processor I've set Image import mode to overwrite existing images but it doesn't work.

My CSV file looks like this:

```
"sku","store","image_label","image","thumbnail","small_image","media_gallery"
"P4208M","admin","MEIA PEUGA HOMEM RFª.4208M  [ANUBIS]","+https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/183676/NET/P4208M.JPG","https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/183676/NET/P4208M.JPG","https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/183676/NET/P4208M.JPG","+https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/183676/NET/P4208M.JPG;+https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/183676/NET/P4208M-1.JPG;+https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/183676/NET/P4208M-2.JPG"
```

Anyone?

Regards
Fabio

Comment: It could be your images are being retrieved through an HTTPS protocol, when Magmi is running in just HTTP.  Have you tried uploading your images to `media/import` instead, and just using the filename in the columns?

Comment: Hi,This works to create images... only when updating it does not work.

Comment: Try checking the permissions in your `media/catalog/product` folder and files within.  CHMOD everything in the folder to 777 temporarily and seeing if the images are overwritten.

Comment: not working neither that way

Answer (score 2):

just happened to me ( magento 1.7, magmi 0.7.18 ): actually magmi work'd fine ( if you set image import mode to override ), you need to flush magento catalog image cache from cache managent. don't know if this is your case, hope this helps :)